# Some similarity of Leibniz and Anaxagoras

Tags: reference-request, ancient-philosophy, leibniz

As early as 1666 Leibniz was able to compose  "*A Conjecture Why It Seems That Anaxagoras Could Have Said That Snow Is Black*" (A II, 1, 4-5). Later, as a librarian, he became extraordinarily well read and knew most of what was preserved from Anaxagoras' views. However his references usually come indirectly by quoting a critical remark made by Socrates in Plato's *Phaedo*.

Today it seems easy to find many similarities between Leibniz' Monadology and Anaxagoras' philosophy. Who was the first to note and/or comment in print such a connection?

Comment: maybe useful: Jürgen Lawrenz, [Leibniz: The Nature of Reality and the Reality of Nature](https://books.google.it/books?id=txoaBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).